# Please critique my proposed architecture: windows service for parsing incoming emails to asp.net database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, windows-services

I have an existing asp.net c# application for which I'd like to implement a feature that allows users to post content via email.  A user would send an email to a designated address and the system would parse the email and create database entries using the email subject, body and any attached images.  My proposed approach is to create a windows service that pings a pop3/imap enabled email provider to retrieve incoming emails.  The service would then parse the emails using an existing library I found here http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/.  The user would be matched according to the email address in the from field to the asp.net membership and then new records would be inserted from the contents of the email for that user.  Initially the windows service would run on a separate EC2 instance that I'll set up for this purpose since the current host does not permit root access.  But eventually I'll probably migrate the entire site to EC2.

Before I dive in I wanted to get some feedback from you all on my overall approach and architecture.  More specifically:

- Is what I described above the approach you would take?
- Would you recommend implementing a web service to manage the interactions between the windows service and the database of the asp.net site? Or would you recommend hitting the database directly?
- If I program the windows service to
  ping the email provider every 30
  seconds, will that be a problem?
- Do you foresee any security issues with this approach I've outlined?
- What about issues with reliability (needs to be a 24x7 service)?

Additional Background --- the asp.net website is an inventory system where each entry has a name, description and optional images.  From the email the subject will become the name, the body will become the description and the images are the images.  If you're familiar with the Posterous blogging platform you'll have an excellent reference point for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is what I described above the approach you would take?

It would be better if you could set up an Exchange server or sth similiar where you get notifications about new emails, so you don't have to ping every 30 minutes, but I never did it this way and cannot tell you if this is even possible.
The approach itself sounds plausible, because sending emails is really easy and everybody knows how to do that.

> Would you recommend implementing a web service to manage the interactions
>   between the windows service and the
>   database of the asp.net site? Or would
>   you recommend hitting the database
>   directly?

I would recommend an extra abstraction layer, because it is not much effort and improves the design. This decreases performance (shouldn't be *that* much), so it depends on your requirements.

> If I program the windows service to ping the email provider every 30
>   seconds, will that be a problem?

Depends on your email provider. Normally and if they allow it: No. You should definetly ask them first.
If it's your own: You're good to go.
There **can** be problems however if you're doing this inside a thread and you're accessing the IMAP multiple times at the same time. You should try to avoid that.

> Do you foresee any security issues with this approach I've outlined?

Yes. You can easily forge the "from" field of an email you've send. There can be issues then, if the email is known. You should definetly add some kind of extra security like sending the mail to `<SaltedHashThatIsDifferentForEachUser>@example.com`. (Facebook does this too for example)

> What about issues with reliability (needs to be a 24x7 service)?

I see more problems with the reliability of your email provider than with your service, because as long as the emails are saved, you can still parse them later.
You should investigate the maximum size of your imap to avoid rejected mails (e.g. delete them once you've successfully parsed them)

Comment: Good catch about the risk of forged emails.  That could be a problem (particularly with spam).  Using a salted hash is one way to go, but that makes for difficult to remember email addresses.  And that's a problem because we're trying to make it easy to post from mobile devices.  I noticed that both facebook and flickr auto-generate unique email addresses whereas posterous uses simply post@posterous.com.  If we wanted to model our approach after the latter, what would your suggestion be for dealing with forged emails?

Answer (score 2):

> Would you recommend implementing a web service to manage the interactions between the windows service and the database of the asp.net site? Or would you recommend hitting the database directly?

There is no need to have a web service, it will just add complexity as well as introduce another attack target on your web server. Having your windows service hit your database directly will be simpler and more secure.

> If I program the windows service to ping the email provider every 30 seconds, will that be a problem?

Should not be a problem ... Email providers provide POP3 and IMAP so that external services can use them (outlook, thunderbird, iphone) so they expect them to be constantly pinged.

> Do you foresee any security issues with this approach I've outlined?

As Simon stated, emails can be easily forged, providing a security vulnerability. This [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEEQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.dustincurtis.com%2Fthoughts-on-the-posterous-hack&rct=j&q=security%20email%20updating%20posterous&ei=4erwTdbMPMa4twfkhtmGAw&usg=AFQjCNGQAUDlRGYjI6du2d24idqlAkMetA&sig2=vmduB2uWV5nzfN41G_eqgA&cad=rja) discusses a hacking incident on posterous and the trade off between ease of use and security. As a CISSP, I tend to lean toward security, especially when the vulnerability very easy to exploit.

The unique, "secret" email address is a better solution in terms of security. However, it takes a lot away from your goal of simplifying the update process.  It also makes your solution more complex and costly since you will need to be able to support (and programmatically create) an unique address for every user.

> What about issues with reliability (needs to be a 24x7 service)?

Most mainstream email providers have outstanding availability.  In regards to the availability of this solution (without the preexisting factors such as your current hardware and hosting facility), you would want to ensure the windows service was well written and included some "fault tolerance".  For example, the services i have written in the past handle a few select errors caused by external dependencies (database or email being unavailable) so that it does not crash but just waits until its back online. This provides better availability since the service is ready to go when the dependency is ok again, without someone required to manually restart the windows service.

> Is what I described above the approach you would take?

Due to the security vulnerability exposed by relying on the sender of the email for authentication and authorization, I would not take this approach.  If the main goal was to simplify and streamline the addition of new items from mobile platforms, I would probably create a "mobile friendly" web page to accomplish this.

I just returned from a web design conference in Seattle and it was heavily focused on "non-pc" platforms.  After listing their very innovative ideas and best practices for designing for the mobile industry, I can see a web app being a great solution to achieving this goal.

Comment: Thanks.  You and Simon both provided really helpful answers.  I considered creating a mobile-friendly web page but the problem is that you cannot access the local photo library (at least not with iPhone...haven't looked at android).  I suppose I could develop a native app but that's a big undertaking, particularly when you consider having to support several OS's.

Comment: there are frameworks where you write the application once and which automatically creates native apps for multiple devices